# Insert value at multiple specified positions into a python string/array

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I would like to insert values at multiple specified positions into a python string/array.

eg for my input string : `SARLSAMLVPVTPEVKPK`

at specified positions: 1,5,12

the desired output: `S*ARLS*AMLVPVT*PEVKPK`

I tried:

```
seq="SARLSAMLVPVTPEVKPK" #string
pos=[1,5,12] #positions
arr=list(seq) #convert string to array
arr.insert(pos,"*") # NOT WORK!
arr.insert(pos[0],"*")
print(''.join(arr))
```

It seems I can only insert a position at a time and thus the indices of the specified positions for the next insert would have to change. 
Is there an elegant way of doing this or would I have to loop through the insert positions adding +1 for each additional insert position?
I hope this make sense!

Many thanks, 
Curly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just insert them in reverse order:

```
seq="SARLSAMLVPVTPEVKPK" #string
pos=[1,5,12] #positions
arr = list(seq)
for idx in sorted(pos, reverse=True):
    arr.insert(idx,"*")
print ''.join(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do:

```
seq="SARLSAMLVPVTPEVKPK" #string
pos=[1,5,12] #positions
arr=list(seq) #convert string to array
_ = map(lambda k: arr.insert(k, "*"), pos[::-1])
print(''.join(arr))
```

or

```
seq="SARLSAMLVPVTPEVKPK" #string
pos=[1,5,12] #positions
arr=list(seq) #convert string to array
for k in pos[::-1]:
    arr.insert(k, "*")
print(''.join(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way:

```
temp =  ""
temp += seq[:pos[0]]
temp += "*"
for i in range(1,len(pos)):
    temp += seq[pos[i-1]:pos[i]]
    temp += "*"
temp += seq[pos[-1]:]
print (temp)    # 'S*ARLS*AMLVPVT*PEVKPK'
```

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is that you're making a new string on each insertion. I have no idea what's the time penalty for this though.

Comment: Temp is a string, strings are inmutable, you make a new string and save it in the temp variable. Anyway, this solution takes less time than mine anyway ^_^